# Prevent R spawned process from exiting on error

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a tool that interacts with an R subprocess, but the process exits whenever R encounters an error.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Here is a simple exemple: as you can see, the process exits as soon as it encounters an error:

```r
library(subprocess)

# Spawning an R process
r <- spawn_process(
  Sys.which("R"), c("--vanilla", "--quiet")
)
Sys.sleep(1)

# Checking and reading the state
process_state(r)
#> [1] "running"
process_read(r)
#> $stdout
#> [1] "> "
#> 
#> $stderr
#> character(0)

# Writing a normal call 
process_write(r, "print(2)\n")
#> [1] 9
Sys.sleep(1)

process_state(r)
#> [1] "running"
process_read(r)
#> $stdout
#> [1] "print(2)" "[1] 2"    "> "      
#> 
#> $stderr
#> character(0)

# Writing a call that will fail
process_write(r, "a\n")
#> [1] 2
Sys.sleep(1)

# The process has exited
process_state(r)
#> [1] "exited"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For example, if we compare with a NodeJS process, it doesn't exits after an error:

```r
library(subprocess)

n <- spawn_process(
  Sys.which("node"), "-i"
)

process_write(n, "a\n")
#> [1] 2

Sys.sleep(1)

process_read(n)
#> $stdout
#> [1] "> Thrown:"                        "ReferenceError: a is not defined"
#> [3] "> "                              
#> 
#> $stderr
#> character(0)

process_state(n)
#> [1] "running"

process_write(n, "console.error('a')\n")
#> [1] 19
Sys.sleep(1)

process_read(n)
#> $stdout
#> [1] "undefined" "> "       
#> 
#> $stderr
#> [1] "a"

process_state(n)
#> [1] "running"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

or with bash:

```r
library(subprocess)

n <-spawn_process(
  Sys.which("bash"), 
)

process_write(n, "a\n")
#> [1] 2

Sys.sleep(1)

process_read(n)
#> $stdout
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $stderr
#> [1] "/bin/bash: line 1: a: command not found"

process_state(n)
#> [1] "running"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though R is being run in batch mode, in which case R will exit if an error is thrown at the top level.  If you add the `--interactive` option then R will continue to run after errors.

```
r <- spawn_process(
  Sys.which("R"), c("--vanilla", "--quiet", "--interactive")
)
```

Comment: Arf, I had tried to pass `-i` but got `"WARNING: unknown option '-i'" ` so thought I wasn't able to pass that options... didn't think to try with `--interactive. Thank you very much, that works!